# Form Validation does not work properly

Tags: php, forms, validation

The form works, it actually validates, if the required fields are not filled in, it won't send the email, however it does not visually tell the viewer.If the code is used on a free standing contact page it works fine. But when incorporated into a one page site with an anchor link, it does not show the error messages, but reloads to the top of the page. Leaving the viewer with no error messages.
Any ideas  See  http://patrickmchugh.com/test/

```
<?php   
// check for form submission - if it doesn't exist then send back to contact form  
if (!isset($_POST['save']) || $_POST['save'] != 'contact') { 
    header('Location: index.php#content2'); exit; 
} 

// get the posted data 
$name = $_POST['contact_name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['contact_email']; 
$subject = $_POST['contact_subject'];
$message = $_POST['contact_message']; 


// check that a name was entered 
if (empty($name)) 
    $error = 'You must enter your name.'; 
// check that an email address was entered 
elseif (empty($email_address))  
    $error = 'You must enter your email address.'; 
// check for a valid email address 
elseif (!preg_match('/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/', $email_address)) 
    $error = 'You must enter a valid email address.'; 
// check that a message was entered 
elseif (empty($message)) 
    $error = 'You must enter a message.'; 

// check if an error was found - if there was, send the user back to the form 
if (isset($error)) { 
    header('Location: index.php?e='.urlencode($error).'#content2'); exit;
} 

// write the email content 
$email_content = "Name: $name\n"; 
$email_content .= "Email Address: $email_address\n"; 
$email_content .= "Subject: $subject\n";
$email_content .= "Message:\n\n$message"; 

// send the email 
mail ("patrick@patrickmchugh.com", "Enquiry from Connolly O'Neill Website", $email_content); 

// send the user back to the form 
header('Location: index.php?s='.urlencode('Thank you for your message.').'#contact2'); exit;
```

?>

Comment: Where do you `echo` out the error messages?

Comment: See this page it is using the same code.This is a freestanding contact page, I want the same thing to happen at the anchor section   http://connollyoneill.com/main/contact.php  so I want it to echo at the contact section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to put page parameter #contact2 or any else #parameter end of the url.
and ur other parameater is before..

header('Location: index.php?s='.urlencode('Thank you for your message.').'#contact2'); exit;

header('Location: index.php?e='.urlencode($error).'#content2'); exit;

Comment: I changed the two lines you mentioned. It returns to the anchor now. Thank you, but the error messages are not working.Is there something else I need to do? see corrected http://patrickmchugh.com/test/

Comment: you have to check if your message is not empty then u have print ur message..
if(strlen($_REQUEST["e"])>0)
{
echo $_REQUEST["e"];
}

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really know what line to put that? Do I replace something with that line? Where do I put that?

Comment: in index file above the "Get in touch" insert code...
and please pass only one parameter name for error msg and successful message.
pass every where one parameter in contact-form-submission.php

and add code
if(strlen($_REQUEST["e"])>0) { echo $_REQUEST["e"]; }

Comment: Ajs Rock. Thanks for all your efforts. And all your time, I cannot understand your reply 100%, I am not fluent in php.  So I cannot get it to work. Can you edit the code as you described? And paste it on here? I would be very much obliged, thank you in advance.

Comment: hi please add code from below i have commented code which one you have to put..

`code` 
<section class="section" id="content2">
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
    <h3>Get In Touch</h3><br>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- error Message display code start -->
  <?php if(strlen($_REQUEST["e"])>0 && $_REQUEST["e"]!="") { ?>
   <div class="alert alert-danger"><?php echo $_REQUEST["e"]; ?></div>
  <?php }?>
 <!-- error Message display code ends -->

<!--Contact Form-->         
 <form action="contact-form-submission.php" method="POST">